# Outlook Forwarding Div Tag Changing Table

Tags: html, outlook

Right now we're trying to develop a system for non-technical salespeople to forward an automatically generated html email to a client. Unfortunately, on forwarding, a *div* tag is added to the table and messes up our formatting.  We aren't able to alter the HTML of the email being generated, so we're hoping to come up with a way to configure Excel not to add the tags.

As a note, we've discovered that using Excel's "resend" feature works, but is difficult to navigate to and would require support in the future.